# how to execute python script in django framework?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, fingerprint

I just wanted to execute python script in django 2. The python script will communicates with  R305 fingerprint scanner. If i pressed a button in webpage, which executes the python script and initiates the sensor.

Need help!

Comment: Depends on the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to implement this is to use a form post in your template to trigger the script on a button press.

**Answer:**

### views.py

```
def press_my_buttons(request):
    if request.POST:
        # Run your script here
        print("Got the POST request")
    return render(request, 'my_template.html')
```

### my_template.html

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Press Me!</button>
</form>
```

> **Note:** While this would get the job done, I would look into trying to use AJAX. 
>   Here is a [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) that could help.

Comment: Where to pass the python file ?? and How ??